# Which server option is widely used with JRuby on Rails?

Tags: jruby

I am experimenting JRuby on Rails and need some guidance/tips in choosing the server. I have used nginx (and passenger) for my RoR in the past.  JRuby wiki page [Servers](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Servers) provide a lot of options and  I have no experience in any of them.

What I am looking for is a simple to install, easy to scale server or the one widely used (so that I can find solutions if I am stuck)

I do realize this might be a broad question and the answer would be `"it depends..."` but would appreciate some pointers.

Comment: Try looking at Torquebox.

Comment: I did but many of the examples use `RVM` and I use `rbenv`. Is there a way I can install `Torquebox` using `rbenv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be biased being on the [Trinidad](http://github.com/trinidad/trinidad) team, but I still think it's top ... esp. as it handles high concurrency well while still being much lighter than **TorqueBox** (which I would also recommend if you do want something beyond just a web server e.g. built-in jobs but be aware that some of it is TB/JRuby specific). Most other options mentioned are Java web servers, which you can rule out if you do not want to install a Java server, [warbling](http://github.com/jruby/warbler) your application and deploying it as a *.war* file.

p.s. for the (next) version **1.5.0** re-deploys are to be revisited and one should be able to do some (memory leak-free) zero-down time deployments.